# Controller Endpoint Naming Convention

Tags: java, c#, .net, controller, routes

I have a controller endpoint and I need help with the naming convention.

Basically, the endpoint is supposed to find a customer by their Id/Email (which is sent in the url of the request). Thus I need to have two endpoints, one for `users/{id}` and one for `users/{email}`.

The issue is, the above wouldn't work as the routes are exactly the same.

What I have done is I have replaces the `users/{email}` route with:

`users/get-by-email/{email}` and kept the get by id route as: `users/{id}`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are creating some kind of REST API for interacting with stored data. In REST, the information you are handling is called a *resource*. You have `users` resource and `emails` resource. My suggestion would be that you could have a `users/{id}` endpoint and `emails/{email}` endpoint, which would return the necessary information. Further, you could also have `users/{id}/emails`, which would return the email addresses of a specific user etc. The purpose of naming the endpoints wisely is to aim for clarity and self-explanation.

The most in-depth discussion: [Fielding, R. Representational State Transfer (REST)](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)

Comment: But emails is a property of the users object, so is id, no? If that was the case you would have: id/{id} and email/{email}

Comment: @AmirAli An email can be an object too, containing values like username, id, address... etc. In terms of naming convention, the endpoint would be more like in my answer than `get-by-email` type of style.

Comment: I agree with you. I've decided to change the endpoint to:
user/{id}
user/email/{email}

Comment: @AmirAli That sounds reasonable as well. As I said, aim for clarity and consistency as the endpoint name might be difficult to change later on. Cheers!

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I've marked your answer as the correct and upvoted. =) Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks! I'll appreciate it! Good luck with your app!